# css background-image unable to resize

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, image-resizing

I have a header image on a page that comes from css:

```
#photos-banner .navbar {
background-image: url("../images/bands/photos.jpg");
border-radius: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;}
```

I then have a nav "on top of" the image:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="scroll active"><a href="#navigation">Home</a></li>
                    <!--  "The Code" Dropdown to go here  -->
                    <li class="upper-links dropdown"><a>The Code <span class="fas fa-angle-down"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="profile-li"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/about.html">About</a></li>
                            <li class="profile-li"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/episodes.html">Episodes</a></li>
                            <li class="profile-li"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/cast.html">Cast</a></li>
                            <li class="profile-li"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/awards.html">Awards</a></li>
                            <li class="profile-li"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/music.html">Music</a></li>
                            <li class="profile-li"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/credits.html">Credits</a></li>
                            <li class="profile-li"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/testimonials.html">Testimonals</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--  /#"The Code" Dropdown to go to here  -->
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/videos.html">Video</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/interviews.html">Interviews</a></li>
                    <!--  /#"Trips" Dropdown to go to here  -->
                    <li class="upper-links dropdown"><a>Trips <span class="fas fa-angle-down"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="magic-egypt-tour-march-2018.html">March 2018</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="magic-egypt-tour-sept-2018.html">September 2018</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll"><a href="magic-egypt-tour-march-2019.html">March 2019</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--  /#"Trips" Dropdown to go to here  -->
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="http://bobveale.com/Newest/courses.html">Courses</a></li>
                    <!--    <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Order</a></li>  -->
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I am trying to have the image resize in sync with the nav but as the image comes from css I can't seem to figure  out how to do it.

The page is here :http://bobveale.com/Newest/csstest.html if anyone's interested.

I've tried numerous things and it's quite easy to get an image to resize when it's in html code (as can be seen at that page) but I'm stumped.

Thoughts, ideas?

Much appreciated
Bob

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size: cover` to fill image in the element. but having the text contained in the image is not a good practice.